# How to filter by ingredients on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, filter, react-hooks

Currently I can filter by 1 ingredient, but when i try to select multiple ingredients (checkboxes), My recipes disappear as "ingredient1, ingredient2" is being passed to my searchfield rather than ingredient 1 & ingredient2.

My code for my search/filter is

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DisplayFoodItems from "./DisplayFoodItems";
import { ingredients } from "../data/Ingredients";

function Search({ details }) {
  const [searchField, setSearchField] = useState("");
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState([]);
  const all = [...checked];
  const filtered = details.filter((entry) => {
    //Search box
    if (entry.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase()) ||
      entry.catagory.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLocaleLowerCase())) {
      return (
        entry.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase()) ||
        entry.catagory.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLocaleLowerCase())
      )
    }
    //Filter checkboxes
    for (var i = 0; i < entry.ingredients.length; i++) {
      console.log(searchField)
      if (entry.ingredients[i].toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLocaleLowerCase())) {
        return (
          entry.ingredients[i].toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLocaleLowerCase())
        );
      }
    }
  }
  );
  const handleToggle = c => () => {
    // return the first index or -1
    const clickedBox = checked.indexOf(c);
    if (clickedBox === -1) {
      all.push(c);
      console.log(all)
      setSearchField(all.toString())

    } else {
      all.splice(clickedBox, 1);
      setSearchField("")
    }
    console.log(all);
    setChecked(all);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <input id="search"
          className="form-control"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search by recipe name or catagory"
          onChange={(e) => setSearchField(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        {ingredients.map((ingredient, index) => (
          <label key={index} className="form-check-label">
            <input
              onChange={handleToggle(ingredient.name)}
              type="checkbox"
              className="mr-2"
            />
            {ingredient.name}</label>
        ))}
        <hr></hr>
      </div>
      <div class="flex">
        <DisplayFoodItems foodList={filtered} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
export default Search;
```

Here is a picture of my screen if it helps at all
[image: my react screen]

All checkboxes work individually but for example, if salt and oil when checked together it should return Bacon wrapped chicken and Smashed potatoes, however it returns blank at present.

[image: filter not showing correct output]

I have tried looping the all array and sending that to setSearchField, but again, I cannot get it to work.

I have tried looping through the array of checked ingredients and sending that to the setSearchField. Im expecting recipes to appear if they contain an ingredient that has been checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want something like this?

```
const foodList = [
    { name: "Food 1", ingredients: ["Salt"] },
    { name: "Food 2", ingredients: ["Oil"] },
    { name: "Food 3", ingredients: ["Milk"] },
    { name: "Food 4", ingredients: ["Salt", "Oil"] },
    { name: "Food 5", ingredients: ["Oil", "Milk"] },
    { name: "Food 6", ingredients: ["Oil", "Salt", "Milk"] },
];
const ingredientList = ["Salt", "Oil", "Milk"]

const Example = () => {
    const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState([]);

    const filtered = foodList.filter(food => {
        return ingredients.length === 0
            || food.ingredients.length > 0 && ingredients.every(selectedIngredient =>
               food.ingredients.some(foodIngredient => foodIngredient.toLowerCase() === selectedIngredient.toLowerCase()));
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Filter</h2>
            {
                ingredientList.map((ingredient, i) => {
                    const checked = ingredients.some(selectedIngredient => ingredient.toLowerCase() === selectedIngredient.toLowerCase());
                    return (
                        <label key={`ingredient-${i}`}>
                            <input
                                type="checkbox"
                                checked={checked}
                                onChange={() => {
                                    if (checked) {
                                        setIngredients(ingredients.filter(selectedIngredient => ingredient.toLowerCase()!== selectedIngredient.toLowerCase()))
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        setIngredients([...ingredients, ingredient]);
                                    }
                                }} />
                            {ingredient}
                        </label>
                    );
                })
            }
            <br />
            <br />
            <h2>Food list</h2>
            <pre>{JSON.stringify(filtered, null, 4)}</pre>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I managed to get it working by changing foodIngredient.toLowerCase() === selectedIngredient.toLowerCase() To
              foodIngredient.toLowerCase().includes(selectedIngredient.toLowerCase())